# What is best way to loop over a list of objects in a HashMap and add new objects to if they aren't over there already?

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I have an object called Paragraph.

```
public class Paragraph {
    private int bookId = -1;
    private int chapterId = -1;
    private int pageNumber = -1;
    private int id = -1;
    private String text = "";
    private String title = "";
}
```

I have a listView with headers and for that i am holding a global list of headers (chaptersList) and a HashMap of header and list of paragraphs for each header:

```
public static List<String> chaptersList;
public static HashMap<String, List<Paragraph>> paragraphsMap;
```

In my adapter i'm getting from the RestAPI data that i transferred into the proper list of headers and same HashMap signature (The list of headers contains values that will be in the Key of the HashMap)

Adapter Signature:

```
public ChapterAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<Paragraph>> listChildData) {
```

What i need do to are two things:

1. Add the new headers to the global headers list. That is easy, getting a header from the list received and searching for it in the global list of headers and if don't exists add to it (maybe there is a better way for that an i will appreciate it if there is a solution for that also, but that is easy).
2. This is the tricky thing. I need to go thru the new HashMap, look for each key to find if this key exists in the global HashMap (paragraphsMap) if the key doesn't exist add it "as is" with all it's values list to the global Paragraphs HashMap.  ELSE: If exists, for that key in the global Paragraphs map, add all the values that are in the HashMap i've received in the constructor parameter to the same key in the ParagraphsMap values list for that specific key.

I can start doing for loops and if and all that bla bla, But I'm guessing that Java and java for android has a better algorithm for that as it is probably a very common scenario (Lazy loading more data while scrolling a ListView and wanting to populate more data from the API and many other scenarios)

p.s. i prefer to do both in one sweep if possible to reduce complexity of algorithm as this is something that will happen many times (every time the user swipe down or up as they might want to get next batch of data or previous batch of data if they started reading in the middle of the chapter and want to get previous paragraphs for example) so there will be lots of API calls and lots of data manipulations over here and it has to work very fast.

I would appreciate every idea.

10x

Comment: "Algorithm"?  No, this is on you.  You're guilty of assuming that it won't be fast enough.  Better to make it work, measure, and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Well i have a for loops style thing. It is not laziness, it is being a good developer that is sure that there are people that did it better and want to learn better ways, what is the problem with that???? That was a very bad comment, sorry! ps. an algorithm is a way to solve a problem... it is spot on the definition....

Comment: This is a very bad question, sorry.  Nobody said you were lazy.  I said you were guilty of pre-mature optimization, which is much worse.

Comment: There's no fancier algorithm than "check if it's there, and if not, add it". Other than, I suppose, correctly implementing `equals` and `hashCode`, and using a `Set` instead of a `List`: then you can just call `add`, and not have to worry about duplicates being added.

Comment: Maybe you will explain why it is a bad question instead of saying it is bad and deduction points to it... as a perfect and amazing developer that had no questions? that might help me and other to understand why not to ask an algorithm question.....

Comment: You should really not worry about **performance**. Worry about **correctness** first. Example: when you intend to you use your Paragraph class within collections, you **most likely** need an equals() and a hashCode() methods; which are probably missing as of now. And using flat int values as "ids" could be a "design smell" as well. Long story short: there are many other things you better look into before worrying about topics like "is my way of adding fast enough".

Comment: I'd wonder why you need a List and a Map.  Dispense with the List and just use the set of keys in the Map.  If you need the set of keys, ask the Map for it.  Redundant design might be your real issue.  A LinkedHashMap will be fast enough.

Comment: The simple answer for that is BaseExpandableListAdapter tutorials show to use it that way... so that is what i am doing

Comment: I've added me solution for the question... if any one want to review it and it might help other people... reducing points for a question is for no research effort or not clear or not useful, not just because you think it is bad... many Java and Android beginners will come across this question exactly. I hope that when you will have question people will help you more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finished up with this code... Thanks for who ever tried to help and try to be more community to whom just was not trying to help...

```
public ChapterAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<Paragraph>> listChildData) {
    this.context = context;
    boolean isValueExists = false;

    // 1. loop over keys in the original paragraphs HashMap
    for (String key : listChildData.keySet() ) {
        List<Paragraph> localParagraphs = listChildData.get(key);
        List<Paragraph> globalParagraphs = GlobalVars.paragraphsMap.get(key);
        // 2.a. Look if this key exists in the global HashMap
        if (GlobalVars.paragraphsMap.containsKey(key)) {
            // 3. Loop over the local (new paragraphs list
            for (Paragraph localValue : localParagraphs) {
                isValueExists = false;
                // Look if the new value exists in the global paragraphs list
                for (Paragraph globalValue : globalParagraphs) {
                    // exists mark as esixt
                    if (globalValue.getId() == localValue.getId()) {
                        isValueExists = true;
                    }
                }
                // if no balue found add it to the paragraphs list
                if (isValueExists == false) {
                    GlobalVars.paragraphsMap.get(key).add(localValue);
                }
            }
        } else { // 2.b. If the key doesn't exists in the global HashMap
            GlobalVars.paragraphsMap.put(key, listChildData.get(key));
            GlobalVars.chaptersList.add(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: People here are occasionally your typical engineer or cs person and want everything done according to the rules unfortunately. It would be nice to have some more humanity, but it's been designed to be strictly Question and Answer. Not saying anything about your question, just commenting on your "more community" comment.

Comment: 10x, As you can see, i have few points and i've helped many people derring my time over here... Never saw something like this before... First time asking a Java question with a Java tag and will think twice asking again those guys... This is really bad... But never mind... My question was legit by all the rules over here... I'm going to leave it with that... moved on to the next part of my app with my solution. 10x man

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to do for loops. If you want to kown what keys of a map are or not present in another map, you only have to compute keysets, using for example commons collections set operations as intersection.

Comment: i am not worried about the keys, keysets is where i would go, more about the looping over the values after i found a key that exists and checking in both list for is an object with a specific id exists in not enter... this is a very long process if not done the right way

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to go through the Hashmap, the nice thing about Hashmaps is that they have quick look up times as long as the hashes are good. Instead you can use the `containsKey(object)` or `containsValue(object)` or even `putIfAbsent(...)` functions to determine if a value is in the hashmap. No need for a loop anywhere unless you're repeatedly checking for a value in hashmap. The process of checking, however, only requires one of the functions above.

If you have to check every key in the new hashmap then you cannot do better than O(n), since you must check every key. In this case there is no better performance than that. You can do the following algorithm (I used pseudocode):

```
foreach(key in newHashMap){
    globalHashMap.put(key,value);
}
```

As you can read in the documentation, the `put(...)` method places the key value pair in the hashmap if it's not there or replaces it if it is there.

link for doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: again the issue is not the keys, the issue is the values... if i find that the key exists i need to go for each object in the list in listChildData HashMap and look for it in the global paragraph HashMap list for the same key... That is thing i am asking for to find what the best way to do. 10x

Comment: 10x, but still, this is not the answer is is only for putting the all value when there is no key in the map already. i was asking for the tricky part of looping over the list of values in on map and looking for them in the other list in the other map... but 10x